# i get this error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-viewpager

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow()' on a null object reference
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3992)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3992)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3992)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3992)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:5641)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:5543)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.removeView(SourceFile:1507)
    at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController$Operation$State.applyState(SourceFile:452)
    at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController$1.run(SourceFile:211)
    at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController$Operation.complete(SourceFile:695)
    at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController$FragmentStateManagerOperation.complete(SourceFile:744)
    at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController$Operation.cancel(SourceFile:597)
    at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController.forceCompleteAllOperations(SourceFile:332)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(SourceFile:3132)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchDestroy(SourceFile:3107)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchDestroy(SourceFile:334)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(SourceFile:330)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy(SourceFile:278)
    at com.demo.base.ui.base.BaseLibActivity.onDestroy(SourceFile:333)
    at com.demo.base.ui.base.BaseActivity.onDestroy(SourceFile:74)
    at com.piaxiya.app.lib_base.view.XJBaseActivity.onDestroy(SourceFile:424)
    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:8762)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1414)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5753)
```

i dont know how to fix it ,no info help me it bothered me for months

I have tried memory recycling and weak nets but they have not reproduced them